# Can I use the update statement with the select statement together in an SqlDataSource?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatasource

My query looks like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="UpdateFullNameSQL" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:UserQueries %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:UserQueries.ProviderName %>" 
        UpdateCommand="update users set firstname = :changefirstname, lastname = :changelastname where username = :currentusername">
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ChangeFirstNameBox" Name="changefirstname" PropertyName="Text" Type="Empty" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ChangeLastNameBox" Name="changelastname" PropertyName="Text" Type="Empty" />
        </UpdateParameters>
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="UsernameBox" Name="currentusername" PropertyName="Text" Type="Empty" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

So I have two parameters that I want to update from and one parameter that I want to use to change the data where it matches withthe selectparameter's data. And when I want to execute it, it shows an ORA-01008 exception. 
My code-behind only has a updatefullnamesql.update(); function.

What am I missing here/doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In update command you should use `@` instead of `:`. I.E.:

```
UpdateCommand="update users set firstname = @changefirstname, 
  lastname = @changelastname where username = @currentusername;"
```

Additionally you have to specify the @currentusername as update parameter

```
<UpdateParameters>
  ...
  <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="UsernameBox" 
    Name="currentusername" PropertyName="Text" Type="Empty" />
</UpdateParameters>
```

Comment: Now I've changed the currentusername to be an updateparameter as well, but when I hit the button, it doesn't do anything, it doesn't show me any errors, it just loads forever.

Comment: It doesn't work with the @ sign, it shows an ORA-00936 missing expression exception.

Comment: @kisbovan93 - ORA-00936 is about missing semicolon at the end of expression; I've updated the example

Comment: Nope, it shows exactly the same error: ora-00936, even with the semicolon unfortunately.